# i uploaded a image files by creating a sub folder in Images Folder dynamically from ModelName but cant retrieve them from that sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

## Here is my Code:

i m using just a simple datalist to display images form folder...

> showing me error after clicking on broke image icon in datalist The resource cannot be found.
>
> > Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
> >
> > > Requested URL: /WebSite2/Images/Desert.jpg

```
protected void BindDataList()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath(@"~/Images/"+Model.Text+"/"));
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
    foreach (FileInfo info in files)
    {
        listItems.Add(info);
    }
    DataList1.DataSource = listItems;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}

protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/"+Model.Text+"/" + filename));
    BindDataList();
}


protected void newfolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string NewDirectory = Server.MapPath("Images/"+Model.Text);
    //New Directory Name in string variable
    CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(NewDirectory);
    //Calling the function to create new directory
}

private void CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(string NewDirectory)
{
    try
    {
        // Checking the existance of directory
        if (!Directory.Exists(NewDirectory))
        {
            //If No any such directory then creates the new one
            Directory.CreateDirectory(NewDirectory);
            Label1.Text = "Directory Created";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Directory Exist";
        }
    }
    catch (IOException _err)
    {
        Label1.Text = _err.Message; ;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this urgent? is there a question?

Comment: i still don't see a question I see a statement

Comment: What is the result? What is not working?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell:
**after click on datalist**
ERROR:
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /WebSite2/Images/557643_326189590821909_1223546738_n.jpg

Comment: Great! How about including this info in your post? By the way: I do not see any slash after `Images/` and `.jpg`. Does this match your code?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: directly copy paste my error page here in above comment..

Answer (score 0):

All path definitions should be rooted with `~/`:

```
protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+Model.Text+"/" + filename));
    BindDataList();
}

protected void newfolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string NewDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+Model.Text);
    //New Directory Name in string variable
    CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(NewDirectory);
    //Calling the function to create new directory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
protected void BindDataList()
{
    var imgDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format(@"~/Images/{0}/", Model.Text));
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(imgDir);
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
    foreach (FileInfo info in files)
    {
        listItems.Add(info);
    }
    DataList1.DataSource = listItems;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}

protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    var imgPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format(@"~/Images/{0}/{1}", Model.Text, filename));

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(imgPath);
    BindDataList();
}

protected void newfolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imgDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format(@"~/Images/{0}/", Model.Text));
    //New Directory Name in string variable
    CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(imgDir);
    //Calling the function to create new directory
}
```

Comment: Where is the difference? (except the first line which is useless in your example) Did you miss something?

Comment: what should i do with var imagPath.

Comment: @Linus Caldwell, Yeah you're right.
Sorry, I'm not yet done with my edit and I talked with my officemate. See my Edit

Comment: throwing me error on **DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(imgPath);** line

Comment: Still showing me error after clicking on broke image icon in datalist **The resource cannot be found.**